# Implement unregister after registration of callback

Tags: javascript, callback

I wrote a simple piece of software that allows users to "register" a function when a state is set.
This was easily achieved by adding functions to an array.
I want to return a function that is able to "unregister" that particular function.
Note that a user might register the same function twice. This means that the "unregistering" function cannot be based on the function as a key in a map

The only thing that springs to mind is making the "register" function way more complex, where each item in the "callbacks" array is not just a function, but an object like this:

```
{
  id: someId
  fn: [the function]
}
```

And that the unregister function will filter the someId value. But I just can't like this.

Ideas?

```
const state = {}
const callbacks = []

const register = (fn) => {
  callbacks.push(fn)
  return () => {
    console.log('Unregister function. HELP!!! How do I do this?')
  }
}

const setState = async (key, value) => {
  state[key] = value
  for (const fn of callbacks) fn(key, value)
}

const getState = (key) => {
  return state[key]
}

const f1 = () => {
  console.log('f1')
}

const f2 = () => {
  console.log('f2')
}

const unregF1a = register(f1)
const unrefF1b = register(f1)
const unregF2 = register(f2)
setState('some', 'a')
unregF1a()
setState('some', 'b')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through your callbacks and remove the desired function (works if the same function is registered twice).
You could do a simple for loop:

```
function unregister(fn) {
  for (let i = callbacks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (callbacks[i] === fn) {
      callbacks.splice(i, 1)
    }
  }
}
```

Or you can use `let` and replace the whole array:

```
let callbacks = [];

function unregister(fn) {
  callbacks = callbacks.filter(cb => cb !== fn)
}
```

---

If you want to be able to register the same function more than once and be able to unregister them independently, then yes, you'll need to track some kind of id.

An id can be something simple, like an increasing integer, and you can store them in a different array, in the same index the function is in the callbacks array (that's hashing).

Something like this:

```
const state = {}
const callbacks = []
const ids = []

let nextId = 0

const register = (fn) => {
  const id = nextId

  callbacks.push(fn)
  ids.push(nextId)
  nextId++

  return () => {
    // find the function position using the ids array:
    const fnIndex = ids.findIndex(cbId => cbId === id)

    if (fnIndex === -1) return // or throw something

    // Now remove the element from both arrays:
    callbacks.splice(fnIndex, 1)
    ids.splice(fnIndex, 1)
  }
}
```

This way, the unregister function always looks for the exact index where the id/fn resides.

Comment: but if I register fn twice, I want to be able to unregister only _one_ specific one, not all of them

Comment: @Merc I believe that would require maintaining an function -> index map and updating it as functions are removed. It’s not difficult but it’s not pretty either.

Comment: This is very close to what I ended up doing independently. Thanks for the answer and for validation.

Comment: If you are curious... https://github.com/mobily-enterprises/reducs -- thanks!

Comment: I think this is one of those questions that will get a gazillion upvotes in time...